# Not able to sign in to Azure Databricks through my Power Bi Desktop

Tags: powerbi, databricks, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have data in a cluster in Azure Databricks. I use Server hostname and Http path to connect to the cluster in power Bi desktop.

But recently my credentials for Azure Databricks changed. It was same as my organization username and password. I changed my organization username and password hence automatically the credentials for my Azure Databricks is also changed.

I use to connect to the cluster earlier without any issues by providing the server hostname path and HTTP path.

But now when I try to do it it says **"we're unable to connect. Please delete your credentials and try again later"**.

There is no way I can see to delete the credentials in powerBi desktop. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Maybe there is a way after all. Did you tried to  go to File -> Options and settings -> Data source settings?

Comment: Yea I did tried, but it is not working. I deleted the permission but still can't sign in

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this option
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/we-re-unable-to-conect-please-delete-your-credentials-and-try/td-p/1126364

File -> Options and settings -> Options -> Global -> Security ->  Authentication Browser -> Use my default web browser (check this box)